# Pandas scientific form values in acolumn gives wrong output after applying minmaxscaler

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, normalization, scientific-notation

I have a dataframe like below.I applied MinMaxScaler on Price column and used inverse_transform function to get back the original price values but it is giving wrong results.Please suggest me on this.

DataFrame:

```
Date    Customer    Price
1/6/2019    A   142404534.13
1/7/2019    A   989.34
1/8/2019    A   45444.57
1/9/2019    A   574343.10
1/10/2019   A   23232.34
1/1/2019    A   923423.00
1/2/2019    A   332.00
1/3/2019    A   2342323.24
1/4/2019    A   232.00
1/5/2019    A   65.70
1/6/2019    B   875.46
1/7/2019    B   142466027340.03
1/8/2019    B   25.17
1/9/2019    B   1.01
1/10/2019   B   1.00
1/10/2019   B   57.61
1/6/2019    B   232232.78
1/7/2019    B   15.20
1/8/2019    B   44.56
1/9/2019    B   2323254.45
1/10/2019   B   395.45
1/10/2019   B   23423454.92
1/6/2019    C   34.12
1/7/2019    C   89.34
1/8/2019    C   44.57
1/9/2019    C   343.10
1/10/2019   C   232.34
```

MinMaxScaler code on df :

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))
    scaler=MinMaxScaler()
    dff = df.groupby('Customer').Price.transform(lambda s:scaler.fit_transform(s.values.reshape(-1,1)).ravel())
dff = pd.DataFrame(dff)
dff['Price'] = dff['Price'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))

dff = pd.concat([dff['Price'] , df['Customer']] , axis=1)
```

dff output:

```
Price   Customer
0   1.00    A
1   0.00    A
2   0.00    A
3   0.00    A
4   0.00    A
5   0.01    A
6   0.00    A
7   0.02    A
8   0.00    A
9   0.00    A
10  0.00    B
11  1.00    B
12  0.00    B
.
.
.
.

20  0.00    B
21  0.00    B
22  0.00    C
23  0.18    C
24  0.03    C
25  1.00    C
26  0.64    C
```

inverse_transform function code to get the actual Price values:

```
dd = dff.groupby('Customer').Price.transform(lambda s: scaler.inverse_transform(s.values.reshape(-1,1)).ravel())

dd = pd.DataFrame(dd)
dd['Price'] = dd['Price'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))
dd = pd.concat([dd['Price'] , df['Customer']] , axis=1)
```

dd output:

```
Price   Customer
0   343.10  A
1   34.12   A
2   34.12   A
3   34.12   A
4   34.12   A
5   37.21   A
6   34.12   A
7   40.30   A
8   34.12   A
9   34.12   A
10  34.12   B
11  343.10  B
12  34.12   B
13  34.12   B
.
.
.
.
.
18  34.12   B
19  34.12   B
20  34.12   B
21  34.12   B
22  34.12   C
23  89.74   C
24  43.39   C
25  343.10  C
26  231.87  C
```

Please help and suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have multiple problems in script:

1. With `df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))` you convert Price column to string, so any numeric operation is not valid on this dtype. If you want to set precision of float on display, you can use `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)` after import pandas line.
2. If I understand well, you want to scale Price values per
   **Customer** range 0-1 values. If that is case, you can not do that in one line like:

   > df.groupby('Customer').Price.transform(lambda
   >   x:scaler.fit_transform(s.values.reshape(-1,1)).ravel())

   because every iteration over scaler object per group overwrite min/max parameters of previous group. So at the end you have parameters of last group when you call scaler.inverse_transform().

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.7f' % x)
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scalers_dict = dict({}) # Prepare place to hold scalers per Customer

df = pd.read_csv('stack_data.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

df['Price_scaled'] = None
df['Price_inverse_scaled'] = None

# Loop over Customers, scale Price and save scaler for further use
for customer in pd.unique(df['Customer']):
    scalers_dict[customer] = MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_price = scalers_dict[customer].fit_transform(df[df['Customer']==customer].Price.values.reshape(-1, 1))
    df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 'Price_scaled'] = scaled_price

# Loop over Customers and inverse scaled values
for customer in pd.unique(df['Customer']):
    inverse_scale = scalers_dict[customer].inverse_transform(df[df['Customer']==customer].Price_scaled.values.reshape(-1, 1))
    df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 'Price_inverse_scaled'] = inverse_scale
```

Output (I set precision to .7f because Max values are too big for many values and most of them became 0.00 in double precision):

```
        Date Customer                Price Price_scaled Price_inverse_scaled
0  2019-01-06        A    142404534.1300000    1.0000000    142404534.1300000
1  2019-01-07        A          989.3400000    0.0000065          989.3400000
2  2019-01-08        A        45444.5700000    0.0003187        45444.5700000
3  2019-01-09        A       574343.1000000    0.0040327       574343.1000000
4  2019-01-10        A        23232.3400000    0.0001627        23232.3400000
5  2019-01-01        A       923423.0000000    0.0064840       923423.0000000
6  2019-01-02        A          332.0000000    0.0000019          332.0000000
7  2019-01-03        A      2342323.2400000    0.0164479      2342323.2400000
8  2019-01-04        A          232.0000000    0.0000012          232.0000000
9  2019-01-05        A           65.7000000    0.0000000           65.7000000
10 2019-01-06        B          875.4600000    0.0000000          875.4600000
11 2019-01-07        B 142466027340.0299988    1.0000000 142466027340.0299988
12 2019-01-08        B           25.1700000    0.0000000           25.1700000
13 2019-01-09        B            1.0100000    0.0000000            1.0100000
14 2019-01-10        B            1.0000000    0.0000000            1.0000000
15 2019-01-10        B           57.6100000    0.0000000           57.6100000
16 2019-01-06        B       232232.7800000    0.0000016       232232.7800000
17 2019-01-07        B           15.2000000    0.0000000           15.2000000
18 2019-01-08        B           44.5600000    0.0000000           44.5600000
19 2019-01-09        B      2323254.4500000    0.0000163      2323254.4500000
20 2019-01-10        B          395.4500000    0.0000000          395.4500000
21 2019-01-10        B     23423454.9200000    0.0001644     23423454.9200000
22 2019-01-06        C           34.1200000    0.0000000           34.1200000
23 2019-01-07        C           89.3400000    0.1787171           89.3400000
24 2019-01-08        C           44.5700000    0.0338210           44.5700000
25 2019-01-09        C          343.1000000    1.0000000          343.1000000
26 2019-01-10        C          232.3400000    0.6415302          232.3400000
```

Edit:
Multiple columns version

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.7f' % x)
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scalers_dict = dict({}) # Prepare place to hold scalers per Customer

df = pd.read_csv('stack_data.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
df['Price2'] = range(df.shape[0])
df['Price3'] = df['Price2'] * 2


df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(0, df.index, ['Price1_scaled', 'Price2_scaled', 'Price3_scaled', 'Price1_inverse_scaled', 'Price2_inverse_scaled', 'Price3_inverse_scaled']))

# Loop over Customers, scale Price and save scaler for further use
for customer in pd.unique(df['Customer']):
    scalers_dict[customer] = MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_price = scalers_dict[customer].fit_transform(df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 'Price':'Price3'])
    df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 'Price1_scaled':'Price3_scaled'] = scaled_price

# Loop over Customers and inverse scaled values
for customer in pd.unique(df['Customer']):
    inverse_scale = scalers_dict[customer].inverse_transform(df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 'Price1_scaled':'Price3_scaled'])
    df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 'Price1_inverse_scaled':'Price3_inverse_scaled'] = inverse_scale
```

Output:

```
         Date Customer                Price  Price2  Price3  Price1_scaled  Price2_scaled  Price3_scaled  Price1_inverse_scaled  Price2_inverse_scaled  Price3_inverse_scaled
0  2019-01-06        A    142404534.1300000       0       0      1.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000      142404534.1300000              0.0000000              0.0000000
1  2019-01-07        A          989.3400000       1       2      0.0000065      0.1111111      0.1111111            989.3400000              1.0000000              2.0000000
2  2019-01-08        A        45444.5700000       2       4      0.0003187      0.2222222      0.2222222          45444.5700000              2.0000000              4.0000000
3  2019-01-09        A       574343.1000000       3       6      0.0040327      0.3333333      0.3333333         574343.1000000              3.0000000              6.0000000
4  2019-01-10        A        23232.3400000       4       8      0.0001627      0.4444444      0.4444444          23232.3400000              4.0000000              8.0000000
5  2019-01-01        A       923423.0000000       5      10      0.0064840      0.5555556      0.5555556         923423.0000000              5.0000000             10.0000000
6  2019-01-02        A          332.0000000       6      12      0.0000019      0.6666667      0.6666667            332.0000000              6.0000000             12.0000000
7  2019-01-03        A      2342323.2400000       7      14      0.0164479      0.7777778      0.7777778        2342323.2400000              7.0000000             14.0000000
8  2019-01-04        A          232.0000000       8      16      0.0000012      0.8888889      0.8888889            232.0000000              8.0000000             16.0000000
9  2019-01-05        A           65.7000000       9      18      0.0000000      1.0000000      1.0000000             65.7000000              9.0000000             18.0000000
10 2019-01-06        B          875.4600000      10      20      0.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000            875.4600000             10.0000000             20.0000000
11 2019-01-07        B 142466027340.0299988      11      22      1.0000000      0.0909091      0.0909091   142466027340.0299988             11.0000000             22.0000000
12 2019-01-08        B           25.1700000      12      24      0.0000000      0.1818182      0.1818182             25.1700000             12.0000000             24.0000000
13 2019-01-09        B            1.0100000      13      26      0.0000000      0.2727273      0.2727273              1.0100000             13.0000000             26.0000000
14 2019-01-10        B            1.0000000      14      28      0.0000000      0.3636364      0.3636364              1.0000000             14.0000000             28.0000000
15 2019-01-10        B           57.6100000      15      30      0.0000000      0.4545455      0.4545455             57.6100000             15.0000000             30.0000000
16 2019-01-06        B       232232.7800000      16      32      0.0000016      0.5454545      0.5454545         232232.7800000             16.0000000             32.0000000
17 2019-01-07        B           15.2000000      17      34      0.0000000      0.6363636      0.6363636             15.2000000             17.0000000             34.0000000
18 2019-01-08        B           44.5600000      18      36      0.0000000      0.7272727      0.7272727             44.5600000             18.0000000             36.0000000
19 2019-01-09        B      2323254.4500000      19      38      0.0000163      0.8181818      0.8181818        2323254.4500000             19.0000000             38.0000000
20 2019-01-10        B          395.4500000      20      40      0.0000000      0.9090909      0.9090909            395.4500000             20.0000000             40.0000000
21 2019-01-10        B     23423454.9200000      21      42      0.0001644      1.0000000      1.0000000       23423454.9200000             21.0000000             42.0000000
22 2019-01-06        C           34.1200000      22      44      0.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000             34.1200000             22.0000000             44.0000000
23 2019-01-07        C           89.3400000      23      46      0.1787171      0.2500000      0.2500000             89.3400000             23.0000000             46.0000000
24 2019-01-08        C           44.5700000      24      48      0.0338210      0.5000000      0.5000000             44.5700000             24.0000000             48.0000000
25 2019-01-09        C          343.1000000      25      50      1.0000000      0.7500000      0.7500000            343.1000000             25.0000000             50.0000000
26 2019-01-10        C          232.3400000      26      52      0.6415302      1.0000000      1.0000000            232.3400000             26.0000000             52.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply , if i want to run the above logic for multiple columns like price , weight and height  , how can i do it

Comment: Just add more lines inside loop with another columns: scaled_price = scalers_dict[customer].fit_transform(df[df['Customer']==customer].Another_column.values.reshape(-1, 1))

Comment: if the dataframe is like in this link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624544/pandas-scale-multiple-columns-at-once-and-inverse-transform-with-groupby/58625090#58625090how should i scale them

Comment: if i have 50 columns ,its not a good idea to keep adding lines , can u please suggest on this

Comment: Then put in scaler whole slice per customer: scaled_price = scalers_dict[customer].fit_transform(df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 'Price':'Price50'])

Comment: In that case you don't need reshape because slice is already 2D

Comment: grtting typeError, when i try to perform code price:price50 ,Error:TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Comment: I give you example how slicing with .loc looks like. You need to make slice acording to your dataset column names.

Comment: can u please pick the code from the link i pasted and try to generate the data

Comment: yes , i have column names 0,1,2,3 , i modified the code in such a way that scaled_price = scalers_dict[customer].fit_transform(df.loc[df['Customer']==customer, 0:3]) , for this it s giving the error

Comment: I edited answer with multiple columns version. Don't forget to accept it.